# Serilog WriteTo Conditional does not log in any path

Tags: c#, azure-functions, serilog

I am writing an HTTP triggered Azure Function in C# (.NET v6.0 isolated) and trying to log to multiple outputs (console, file, 2 DB tables) using Serilog. I tried the `WriteTo.Conditional` command, but when tested it does not write to any of the options. I am using the Log Levels as conditions. The configuration for each of the log outputs used has been tested separately (`WriteTo.Console1`, `WriteTo.File`, `WriteTo.MSSqlServer`) and it works. Below is my configuration inside Program.cs:

```
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Conditional(
            ev =>
            {
                bool isDebug = ev.Equals(LogEventLevel.Debug);
                if (isDebug) { return true; }
                return false;
            },
            wt => wt
                .Console()
            )
        .WriteTo.Conditional(
            ev =>
            {
                bool isDebug = ev.Equals(LogEventLevel.Debug);
                if (isDebug) { return true; }
                return false;
            },
            wt => wt
                .File("log.txt")
            )
        .WriteTo.Conditional(
            ev => {
                bool isInformation = ev.Equals(LogEventLevel.Information);
                if (isInformation) { return true; }
                return false;
            },
            wt => wt
                .MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: dbConnection,
                    sinkOptions: sinkOptsHead,
                    columnOptions: columnOptsHead
                )
            )
        .WriteTo.Conditional(
            ev => {
                bool isWarning = ev.Equals(LogEventLevel.Warning);
                if (isWarning) { return true; }
                return false;
            },
            wt => wt
                .MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: dbConnection,
                    sinkOptions: sinkOptsDetails,
                    columnOptions: columnOptsDetails
                )
            )
        .CreateLogger();
```

I have also enabled the Serilog Self Log option, but nothing is happening this time.

```
        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
        {
            Debug.Print(msg);
            Debugger.Break();
        });
```

The debug commands inside my function are:

```
 logger.LogDebug("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
 logger.LogInformation("{GLOBAL_UUID}{USE_CASE}{ORDER_STATUS}{TIMESTAMP}", guid, useCase, orderStatus, DateTime.Now);
 logger.LogWarning("{GLOBAL_UUID}{USE_CASE}{REQUEST_UUID}{SERVICE}{END_SYSTEM}{STATE}{PAYLOAD}{TIMESTAMP}{LEVEL_TYPE}", 
                  guid, useCase, Guid.NewGuid(), service, context.GetType, orderStatus, req.Body, DateTime.Now, levelType);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach.

```
Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Logger(a =>
                {
                    a.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(a => a.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Debug)
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.File("warning.log");
                })
                .WriteTo.Logger(a =>
                {
                    a.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(a => a.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: dbConnection,
                                         sinkOptions: sinkOptsHead,
                                         columnOptions: columnOptsHead
                                        );
                })
                .WriteTo.Logger(a =>
                 {
                     a.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(a => a.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
                     .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString: dbConnection,
                                          sinkOptions: sinkOptsDetails,
                                          columnOptions: columnOptsDetails
                                         );
                 })
                 .CreateLogger();
```

Hope it helps.